# Inserting a curl response as a variable into HTML

Tags: php, html, curl, consul

I'm using Consuls KV store to store some data. You can retrieve these values through a simple HTTP API curl command such as:

```
curl https://consul.rocks/v1/kv/my-key?raw
```

To return the unencoded value

Is there anyway I can inject/insert the returned value as a variable into some HTML. I have no experience of front-end web development so unsure if this is applicable or feasible

Comment: read about ajax

Comment: Is this a question about PHP, or do you just want to be able to fetch it directly via a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement curl values using PHP. Assuming you are new to web-development, I suggest you read about backend as well since it is critical for what you want to do.

Here is a rundown of what you need to do:

1. We want to insert an PHP tag into the document to get the curl value, so change the file extension to `.php`. Remember that you need to have php installed on you're server for this to work.
2. In the element where you want the curl value to be placed in, insert the following: 
   `<?php echo curl_exec(curl_init("https://consul.rocks/v1/kv/my-key?raw")); ?>`